# HDD activity causes lag

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, performance, 64-bit, disk-activity

Whenever there is activity on the main HDD, my PC starts to lag. Most noticeably, the audio starts to stutter and slow down, and the fps in games drops by over 50%.

It gets worse as hard drive activity increases.
For example, if I start copying a large file to or from the hard drive, the audio and video playback gets deformed completely. 
I've ran resource monitor and found nothing wrong. There are no CPU spikes or anything similar. Also, this happens only when the main hard drive is in use (the one with the OS). I have another hard drive, and it does not cause performance drops when busy (I can copy the same large file within the other HDD with not problems).

I checked the HDD with Seagate's official utility and it reported no problems. HDD model is ST3500413AS. I've had this problem for a few months, but it wasn't nearly as bad as it is now. Is my HDD dying? Any other checks I can do?

Comment: Check your memory usage in Task Manager. If >75% is in use you may be running out of usable memory for the system. In that case, it uses the HDD for system memory, which is slower and slows everything down.

Comment: I assume you've run a defrag on the drive?  Also, you might consider setting a fixed swap file size.  Another possibility is that your hard disk is close to capacity, so the OS has difficulty finding space for temporary files.

Comment: Memory usage rarely goes over 30%. The HDD is close to it's capacity. Defragmenter says that the C drive is 6% fragmented. I will free some space, run the defragment, set a fixed swap size, and report after.

Comment: The defragmenter took a good 11 hours. I have cleared a lot of hdd space, and set a fixed page file. The problem is still there. :(